# Combining names of objects with numbers in object variables

Tags: vb.net

I have a lot of very similarly named objects and I would like to know if there is any way to combine an object and with a number.

I haven't been able to find any way of doing this.

```
Dim chkBox As Object
For i = 0 To 3
            For n = 1 To 27
                chkBox = chkKeypadModule & n
                If (chkBox.Checked = True) And (aryNumbers(0) <> 1) And (aryNumbers(1) <> 1) And (aryNumbers(2) <> 1) And (aryNumbers(3) <> 1) Then
                    aryNumbers(Index) = 1
                ElseIf (chkKeypadModule2.Checked = True) And (aryNumbers(0) <> 2) And (aryNumbers(1) <> 2) And (aryNumbers(2) <> 2) And (aryNumbers(3) <> 2) Then
                End If
            Next n
        Next i
```

What I expect is to be able to run a for loop and change the object that is looked at depending in the index. There doesn't seem to be a way to do this

Comment: An `Object` does not have a `.Checked` property.

Comment: Look into `AndAlso`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use an array.

Try this code (which I simplified because you seem to have a lot of superfluous code):

```
Dim chkKeypadModules = { chkKeypadModule1, chkKeypadModule2, chkKeypadModule3, chkKeypadModule4, chkKeypadModule5, chkKeypadModule6, chkKeypadModule7, chkKeypadModule27 }
Dim chkBox As CheckBox
For n = 0 To chkKeypadModules.Length - 1
    chkBox = chkKeypadModules(n)
    If chkBox.Checked Then
        aryNumbers(Index) = 1
    End If
Next n
```

You need to make sure you include all of the `chkKeypadModule1{n}` in the array.

Comment: With Option Strict an object does not have a `.Checked` property. Why not just define `chkBox As CheckBox`?

Comment: Otherwise Cast chkBox to CheckBox but I thought boxing and unboxing are frowned upon.

Comment: @Mary - You're right - I should have changed `Object` to `CheckBox`. Mind you, though, there's no boxing here - boxing only occurs when you cast a value-type as a reference-type (i.e. as an `Object` or an interface). Because `CheckBox` is a reference-type there's no boxing when casting to `Object` (or visa-versa).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I never really understood; I just try to stay away from object when I can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to search for the controls, using [`Controls.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find):

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 3
    For n As Integer = 1 To 27
        Dim arrCtrl() As Control = Me.Controls.Find("chkKeypadModule" & n, True)

        If arrCtrl.Length = 1 Then
            chkBox = arrCtrl(0)

            If chkBox.Checked AndAlso aryNumbers(0) <> n AndAlso aryNumbers(1) <> n AndAlso aryNumbers(2) <> n AndAlso aryNumbers(3) <> n Then
                aryNumbers(i) = n    
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```